# Cronjob permission denied (Nightly backup shell script)

Tags: permissions, scripts, backup, cron

I am trying to create a shell script to make a backup every night using tar.

The error I get is:

```
From shady@wserver1  Wed Dec 30 04:01:01 2015
Return-Path: <shady@wserver1>
X-Original-To: shady
Delivered-To: shady@wserver1
Received: by wserver1 (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id 23DBE15620F5; Wed, 30 Dec 2015 04:01:01 -0500 (EST)
From: root@wserver1 (Cron Daemon)
To: shady@wserver1
Subject: Cron <shady@wserver1> /home/shady /backup.sh
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/shady>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=shady>
Message-Id: <20151230090101.23DBE15620F5@wserver1>
Date: Wed, 30 Dec 2015 04:01:01 -0500 (EST)

/bin/sh: 1: /home/shady: Permission denied
```

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
####################################
#
# Backup to NFS mount script.
#
####################################

# What to backup. 
backup_files="/home /var/www /var/lib/mysql"

# Where to backup to.
dest="/media/backups"

# Create archive filename.
date=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S")
hostname=$(hostname -s)
archive_file="$hostname-$date.tgz"

# Print start status message.
echo "Backing up $backup_files to $dest/$archive_file"
date
echo

# Backup the files using tar.
tar czf $dest/$archive_file $backup_files

# Print end status message.
echo
echo "Backup finished"
date

# Long listing of files in $dest to check file sizes.
ls -lh $dest
```

It works fine if I run the command using `sudo su`, but I can't do that with a cron job. The permissions are very strict for `/var/lib/mysql`, but I could always back that up manually if it comes to that. However, `/home` and `/var/www` are both set to `775` and it's still not working. Any help?

Comment: When I say "both set to 775 and it's still not working", what I mean is even when removing /var/lib/msql from the folders I want to backup, and only backing up the other two, it still gives me permission denied error.

Comment: What user did you cron the task as?

Comment: Maybe the permission denied is for the script. Did you try `sudo chmod a+x /path/to/your/script`?

Comment: I do not know what that means. That's a good thing though, as it means that might be the problem. 

I used this tutorial to setup the chron job. http://broexperts.com/2012/06/how-to-backup-files-and-directories-in-linux-using-tar-cron-jobs/


All I did was:
    crontab -e

Comment: the script is 775 as well.

Comment: Apparently you're running `/home/shady /backup.sh`. Is that space intentional?

Answer (score 4):

- shady user doesn't have permission to execute backup.sh file for auto cron job
- try to run it fist manually with shady user also set permission for backup.sh

  ```
  chmod +x backup.sh
  ```